# java swing minimal (or range for) font size for other application

Tags: java, swing, fonts, themes, nimbus

For swing applications, default font settings for components are in current theme and can be retrieved using UIManager:

```
public class JavaTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(UIManager.get("Label.font"));
    }
}
```

This can be adjusted in JAVA_HOME/lib/swing.properties for range of applications with for example:

```
swing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
```

or set at command line with:

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel MyApp
```

Or the application itself remembers it's look and feel and has this value stored somewhere in configuration (file). It works, because application can set look and feel for itself, e.g.:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

This all looks nice, but applications need often **smaller fonts** (e.g. unimportant status bar message for Label) or **larger fonts** (Label with some heading). **Is there any recommended way for this?**
As a user of high density monitor I had to discard lot of java applications, that use code like this - source code copied from squirrel sql:

```
Font tmp = (Font)UIManager.get("Label.font");
if (tmp != null) {
        Font font = tmp.deriveFont(10.0f);
        _statusBarFontInfo = new FontInfo(font);
}
```

This example code makes status bar completely unreadable, but most components are adjusted to new, bigger font.

For creating my own application, I might use some **ratio** (e.g. 50% to 150% of theme font), but **hardcoding 0.50 - 1.50 range looks** as a **bad** coding habbit as well. And it doesn't fix problem with applications that I don't have source code for. This belongs to the theme / L&F (Look & Feel, Look and Feel). Example:

```
FontUIResource Label_font_resource = (FontUIResource)javax.swing.UIManager.get("Label.font");
Font Label_font = Label_font_resource;
Font Label_font_bigger = Label_font.deriveFont(Label_font.getSize2D() * 1.5f);
```

It's worth asking before I try some ugly hacks like custom components replacing swing default ones, or Graphics2D.setFont adjustments, or any other scary stuff. :-)

**Edit**: the only thing that exists, is size variant, which is supported only by Nimbus theme. Allowed values are "mini", "small", "regular", "large". Example:

```
JComponent mini = new JButton("mini");
mini.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "mini");
```

However, looking into source code for Nimbus theme, it's not possible to simply adjust these values (e.g. scale to 150% for "large"), it's actually hard-coded!

```
package javax.swing.plaf.nimbus;

public final class NimbusStyle extends SynthStyle
{
  public static final String LARGE_KEY = "large";
  public static final String SMALL_KEY = "small";
  public static final String MINI_KEY = "mini";
  public static final double LARGE_SCALE = 1.15D;
  public static final double SMALL_SCALE = 0.857D;
  public static final double MINI_SCALE = 0.714D;
```

This value can be edited only by very advanced user (for example edit constant pool in JAVA_HOME/lib/rt.jar with program called "rej") - i tried it, and it works, BUT it doesn't work always, because they actually hard-coded (!!) the constants at several places (is this really best quality - standard library?), for example:

```
if ("large".equals(str))
{
    this.scrollBarWidth = (int)(this.scrollBarWidth * 1.15D);
    this.incrGap = (int)(this.incrGap * 1.15D);
    this.decrGap = (int)(this.decrGap * 1.15D);
}
```

**Bottom line: no, Java look and feel doesn't support that for now. I suggest using ratios, e.g. 0.7 - 1.3 of default font size.**

```
JLabel smallLabel = new JLabel("some text");
smallLabel.setFont(smallLabel.getFont().deriveFont(0.8f * smallLabel.getFont().getSize2D()));
```

Comment: [nice question +1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9958004/714968)

Comment: Removed tag "Nimbus". This has nothing to do with theme "Nimbus", it was just an example. It concerns ALL themes.

Comment: in Swing are Look and Feel, not themes

Comment: Yes, but I like word "theme" more, I included (in the original post) all names "theme / L&F (Look & Feel, Look and Feel)". You obviously understood my comment with only word "theme" anyway.

Comment: only slightly related: as a general rule, applications should respect the _user's_ font setting (instead of second-guessing by f.i. trying to calculate sizes by dpi) Unfortunately, [Swing isn't overly well-behaved](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11309861/203657) in that area.

Comment: Thanks for link, yes, respecting user's font is good idea. Nevertheless, the question still stands - how big or small should it be, compared to user's font settings, in case larger or smaller font is needed?

Comment: I added "nimbus" tag in the end anyway, because it's actually the only theme, that tries (very stupid way, and unsuccessfully) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the `Font`, Nimbus has a `sizeVariant` for mini, small, regular and large components. This article has more examples: [Resizing a Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html).

```
myButton.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "mini");
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in my Swing applications is include a Font class.  Every other Swing component that needs a font calls the Font class.

```
import java.awt.Font;

public class MinesweeperFont {

    protected static final String FONT_NAME = "Comic Sans MS";

    public static Font getBoldFont(int pointSize) {
        return new Font(FONT_NAME, Font.BOLD, pointSize);
    }

}
```

Now in this case, I only needed one font type.  I let the application pick the font size.

You could define a method for each font size you want, probably calling them small, medium, and large, so you can change the methods later to use a different point size or type if you want.

Since your entire application calls these font static methods, you only have to make font changes in one place.

Comment: I am describing your solution in my question as unsatisfactory: see the bold "ratio" part. I am asking if it can be done BETTER - to share settings among Java applications (like "Look and feel"), and/or how to fix it for existing Java applications that use absolute font size, not proportional.