# Why does Font load differently on different jres?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I am trying to load a font to a label/button text on a swing app written in java 1.4.
For some reason, the font loads without exception, but displays a completely diff font on the button.
When I run the same code on 1.5 jre, it appears to work ok. Why does this happen?

**UPDATE**
Printing a sysout on 1.4, 1.5 shows this:

jre 1.5 : java.awt.Font[family=Futura LT,name=Futura LT Medium,style=bold,size=14]

jre 1.4 : java.awt.Font[family=dialog,name=Futura LT Medium,style=bold,size=14]

The font name family is different! Why is that?

Below is an image to how it looks on diff jres (left is 1.5, right is 1.4)

[image]

### Code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.MultiSplitLayout;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.MultiSplitPane;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.MultiSplitLayout.Node;



/**
 * 
 * @author Hans Muller (Hans.Muller@Sun.COM)
 */
public class Example2 extends Example {
    protected void initialize(String[] ignore) {
        super.initialize(ignore);

        String layoutDef = "(COLUMN (LEAF name=column1 weight=0.25) (LEAF name=column2 weight=0.25) (LEAF name=column3 weight=0.25) (LEAF name=column4 weight=0.25) )";
        Node modelRoot = MultiSplitLayout.parseModel(layoutDef);

        MultiSplitPane multiSplitPane = new MultiSplitPane();
        multiSplitPane.setDividerSize(5);
        multiSplitPane.getMultiSplitLayout().setModel(modelRoot);
        JButton comp = new JButton("TEST TEXT");
        comp.setFont(loadFont("FuturaLT.ttf",14,Font.BOLD));
        multiSplitPane.add(comp, "column1");
        multiSplitPane.add(new JButton("Test Text"), "column2");
        Container cp = mainFrame.getContentPane();
        cp.add(multiSplitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static Font loadFont(String fontName, float size, int style) {

        InputStream openStream = FontColorScheme.class
                .getResourceAsStream("resources/fonts/FuturaLT/"
                        + fontName);
        ;
        try {
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, openStream);
            Font finalFont = font.deriveFont((float) size).deriveFont(style);
            System.out.println("Loading font " + fontName + " " + finalFont);
            return finalFont;
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (openStream != null) {
                try {
                    openStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "off");
        Runnable doCreateAndShowGUI = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Example2 app = new Example2();
                    app.initialize(args);
                    app.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TBD log an error
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doCreateAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like two different look and feels

Comment: As an aside, why are you trying to write code for obsolete JREs?  I doubt many people would (still) care what fonts Java 1.5 or 1.4 use, *or* how they render..

Comment: @MadProgrammer the code is all that. doing nothing different for look and feels.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Some organizations will not move to a new version of Java unless they are forced to move.  It took us 6 months to move to Java 1.5 because of all the code changes and code testing we had to do because we used enum as a field name in a few hundred classes.  We're currently at 1.6 with no plans to move to 1.7 until we are forced to move by Glassfish updates.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc  *"Some organizations.."*  Yes, yes - I know there are multiple reasons why the OP **might** need to code for an older JRE, but I want to know the ***actual*** reason in this case.

Answer (score 2):

rendering is correct, there are three areas

- `Font` used `LookAndFeel` (`Metal` and `Windows`)
- `Font` and NativeOS, [more in question by @kleopatra about Win7, everything depends of theme and setting for Font, rendering, areo ....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309861/bug-or-feature-swing-default-gui-font-incorrect-for-win6), too lazy to test in Win8
- `Java2d`, `Graphics(2D)` in `Java1.4.xxx`, there are changes in core, because output compiled in `Java1.5.xxx` is very similair to todays `Java6/7`

Comment: @Jay don't know if is possible to set Ocean theme in Java1.4.xxx  (Metal L&F in =>Java5), every constants including L&F are in [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) by camickr

Answer (score 1):

This can have many reasons. To understand this better, you should print the font that Java is using:

```
 System.out.println(button.getFont().toString());
```

That should answer the question whether both JREs use the same default font. If they do, make sure the font is a TrueType font (TTF) and not a bitmap font; bitmap fonts don't scale well. While TTF does scale better, some fonts look bad at certain sizes. So a font might look well at 10 and 12 pixel but odd at 11.

To solve the issue, either set the font yourself, chose a different font if you already override the system default or try to tweak the font size.

Comment: @AaronDigulla  For some reason I missed that comment earlier.  Noise deleted.